# How to refresh ListView in JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, refresh

Sorry for bothering with such wide explained topic. 
I have been creating dialog to pick string values from one list to another. There is list of options at the start. get/setSourceItems and get/setTargetItems are getters and setters for ObservableLists

```
private ListView<String> sourceListView;
private ObservableList<String> sourceItems;
private ListView<String> targetListView;
private ObservableList<String> targetItems;

        List<String> options = getSelectedMetaDataList();
        setSourceItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(options));
        sourceListView = new ListView(getSourceItems());
        setTargetItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList()));
        targetListView = new ListView(getTargetItems());
```

Dialog shows listViews well at the start. Source is filled with options and target is empty.
But when I use button then nothing happens on UI.
For example when I move all items from source to target I can see items in targetItems observableList but nothing in targetListView on UI.

```
        Button selectAllBtn = new Button(">>");
            selectAllBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (getSourceItems().size() > 0) {
                        setTargetItems(getSourceItems());
                        targetListView.refresh();
                        setSourceItems(null);
                        sourceListView.refresh();
                        System.out.println("selectAllBtn target: " + getTargetItems().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Something wrong is with selection model too. Because when I try move selected items sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems() is empty even when I have item highlighted. I tried to move items not only by observableList but using targetListView.getItems().addAll(movingItems);
Still no changes on UI.

```
        Button selectOneBtn = new Button(">");
            selectOneBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    ObservableList<String> movingItems = sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
                    System.out.println("selectOneBtn: " + sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size());
                    System.out.println("selectOneBtn: " + targetListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size());
                    if (movingItems.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("selectOneBtn: " + movingItems.toString());
                    sourceListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    sourceListView.getItems().removeAll(movingItems);
                    sourceListView.refresh();
                    targetListView.getItems().addAll(movingItems);
                    targetListView.refresh();
                    System.out.println("selectOneBtn source: " + getSourceItems().toString());
                    System.out.println("selectOneBtn target: " + getTargetItems().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You my friend have complicated a simple task.

Comment: I suggest you get rid of your setters and getters and use ListView and ObservableList as they were intended.

Comment: Or at least get rid of the setters. `ObservableList`s generally work best if they are final. Since they are modifiable, there is rarely any need to change the references to point to a new list.

Answer (score 3):

You change the underlying observable list, but you never tell the list view to use the new list:

```
Button selectAllBtn = new Button(">>");

selectAllBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (getSourceItems().size() > 0) {
            setTargetItems(getSourceItems());

            targetListView.setItems(getTargetItems());

            // use an empty list, not null:
            setSourceItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

            sourceListView.setItems(getSourceItems());

            System.out.println("selectAllBtn target: " + getTargetItems().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, instead of changing to a new list, just change the contents of the existing list. Since the lists are observable, the listviews will see the changes automatically:

```
Button selectAllBtn = new Button(">>");

selectAllBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (getSourceItems().size() > 0) {

            getTargetItems().setAll(getSourceItems());

            getSourceItems().clear();

            System.out.println("selectAllBtn target: " + getTargetItems().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

For your selection problem, you get a reference to the list of selected items:

```
 ObservableList<String> movingItems = sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

and then you clear the selection:

```
 sourceListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

which will, of course, make the list of selected items empty.

So now when you do

```
 sourceListView.getItems().removeAll(movingItems);
 targetListView.getItems().addAll(movingItems);
```

you are passing in an empty list each time, and so nothing will change.

Instead, copy the selected items:

```
List<String> movingItems = new ArrayList<>(sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

and then

```
sourceListView.getItems().removeAll(movingItems);
targetListView.getItems().addAll(movingItems);
```

will have the desired effect (no need to call `refresh()`).

Here is a SSCCE (note I unified both behaviors into a single method, since they are essentially the same):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoveItemsBetweenListViews extends Application {

    private ObservableList<String> sourceItems;
    private ObservableList<String> targetItems;



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        sourceItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
        targetItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ListView<String> sourceListView = new ListView<>(sourceItems);
        ListView<String> targetListView = new ListView<>(targetItems);

        Button moveAllButton = new Button(">>");
        Button moveSelectedButton = new Button(">");

        moveAllButton.setOnAction(e -> moveItems(sourceItems));
        moveSelectedButton.setOnAction(e -> moveItems(sourceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

        VBox buttons = new VBox(10, moveAllButton, moveSelectedButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(buttons, null, targetListView, null, sourceListView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void moveItems(List<String> itemsToMove) {
        List<String> movingItems = new ArrayList<>(itemsToMove);
        sourceItems.removeAll(movingItems);
        targetItems.addAll(movingItems);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer.
I tried both your suggestions about refresh but nothing changes.
Now I found that sourceItems and targetItems are defined as ObservableList<String>. I read somewhere that correct type si ObservableListArray.

Comment: @EduardNickel No, `ObservableList<String>` is correct. If it's still not working, something else is wrong in the code you haven't posted. See update, which includes a working SSCCE.

Comment: Thank you. SSCCE is great and works fine. What could have effect on such simple behaviour? As I wrote, my button are in dialog. Maybe this influence whole process :(

Comment: At the start of selectOneBtn when I define movingItems, I write values into log before I clear selection.
Mystery is that both values of getSelectedItems are 0 :(

Comment: @EduardNickel No one can possibly know what is wrong with code you haven't posted. If the provided answer is not answering your question, you should update the question to provide a full [MCVE] that demonstrates the issue. As it stands, this answer provides a solution to the problem you actually posted.

Comment: @EduardNickel Do not post your entire project. Create (from scratch if necessary) a [MCVE]. Just the smallest complete application that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have made some tries and I found that problem is Dialog definition. I defined Dialog in method which creates context menu to show dialog. When I moved Dialog definition into start method, ListViews have started work fine. Thank you again for many useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to do something similar to this.

```
@FXML ListView lv1, lv2;

ArrayList options = new ArrayList();
ObservableList<String> items;

ObservableList<String> items2;


//This is used to get the selected item from lv1 and add it to lv2
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    items2.add(lv1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());             
}

//This is used to get all items from lv1 and add them to lv2
@FXML 
private void handleGetAllButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{
    for(String entry : items)
    {
       items2.add(entry);
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO

   options.add("hello");
   options.add("bye");
   options.add("hola");
   items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(options);
   items2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   System.out.println(items.size());
   lv1.setItems(items);
   lv2.setItems(items2);

}
```

Comment: @Eduard How did it go?